# Not Like in MySQL select statement not returning correct result

Tags: mysql

```
$query = "
    SELECT distinct count(*) as num 
    FROM table1 ge 
    INNER JOIN table 2 ad 
    ON ge.ID = ad.ID 
    WHERE ge.ID = ad.ID AND ge.field LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['search'])."%' 
    AND ge.field not like '%word%' 
    order by ge.field ASC"
```

Or

```
$query = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 ge 
    INNER JOIN table 2 ad 
    ON ge.ID = ad.ID 
    WHERE ge.ID = ad.ID AND ge.field LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['search'])."%' 
    AND ge.field not like '%word%' 
    order by ge.field ASC"
```

Can't seem to get the correct result from this query, any record with `$word` should not be displayed? Any help much appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: Is `$word` a variable or the string `'word'`?

Comment: btw Your first query looks weird, you can do a `COUNT()` without `group by` but then you dont need `DISTINCT`. So if you are worry for multiple result you are missing `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is you debug what is the value of your variable and try to execute direct on the db.

Looks like you try to use `'word'` as string instead using it as a variable.

```
$query = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 ge 
    INNER JOIN table 2 ad 
    ON ge.ID = ad.ID 
    WHERE ge.ID = ad.ID AND ge.field LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['search'])."%' 
    AND ge.field not like '%".$word."%' 
    order by ge.field ASC"
```

Comment: Yes, it is a string and when running the "not like" via my phpAdmin the response is as expected records before query 10 after 4 which is spot on, but when I run the same through using "select query" no difference still researching. $str = 'keyword'; "select * from table where id=$id and field not like '%str_word%'" should not display any records. I'm stumped, don't know if something is conflicting or overriding... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mysql syntactical query looks good to ignore records containing with "word". 
However, per question, it looks like "$word" is a variable and you want to ignore records containing the value of $word. Find the suggested edit as below.

```
$query = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 ge 
    INNER JOIN table 2 ad 
    ON ge.ID = ad.ID 
    WHERE ge.ID = ad.ID AND ge.field LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['search'])."%' 
    AND ge.field not like '%".$word. "%' 
    order by ge.field ASC"
```

Comment: Tried the above query and same result, all record are displayed, thanks

Comment: Even tried straight string for testing purposes "AND ge.field not like '%string%' but it works in mysql correctly, continuing my test.

Comment: Can you try printing the $query variable and try running the generated query in mysql?